# VB.NET Iterators: passing objects to an iterator works well but what happens when you do it?

Tags: .net, vb.net

[VB.NET Iterators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/iterators) have come in quite handy for iterating through nodes (in simple and complex trees) and letting the iterator handle the specifics of the specific tree.

In the Microsoft documentation I read this however: **"In Visual Basic, an iterator method cannot have any ByRef parameters."**

I am passing in objects as a key argument to the iterator however, simplified like this:

```
Public Iterator Function FilteredNodes(Nodes as NodesCache, Filter as String) as IEnumerable(Of Node)
End Function
```

and used in code like this:

```
For Each Node in FilteredNodes(LocalNodesCache,"*")
Next
```

This works really well and performs more than adequately. The NodesCache object has a lot of references to other objects (that are part of the cached tree) and they are guaranteed not to change while the iterator is running (to avoid any side-effects).

I would like to understand what happens in the background however.

I theorize the object I pass in to the Iterator (the NodesCache) is copied as it is automatically passed in ByVal, but the objects it references are not (deep) copied and passed ByVal.

However I have no idea if this is actually so, if you can share your insights and understanding in to what actually happens with the object (and the objects it references) that is passed as an argument to the iterator thank you!

(in the future, nodes structures may become so large they will be read from a large file, so an iterator is handy to not have to read entire files at once, and the code using the iterator can remain very simple which has already simplified my code)

Comment: *"the object I pass in to the Iterator (the NodesCache) is copied as it is automatically passed in ByVal"*. Why would that be the case? Why would you think that passing by value would create a copy? See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77065821/does-implementing-and-calling-istrue-operator-create-copy-of-the-class-instance) and take the advice provided.

Comment: Ok thank you jmcilhinney it is just that it seemed the reason ByRef is not possible is to prevent changes outside the iterator happening during iteration causing issues in the iterator. Just copying the reference hardly prevents any of those issues, only if the reference is changed but that is like solving just half a problem (or even less).

Comment: ByRef would allow the procedure to change the value, which would be visible to the calling code. However, as an iterator can return many values, when is the correct time to see that change? As there is no correct answer, it is forbidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I theorize the object I pass in to the Iterator (the NodesCache) is copied as it is automatically passed in ByVal,

This is only correct if `NodesCache` is a `Structure`, which seems unlikely. In .Net, if you have a reference type (any Module or Class... even basic strings and arrays are references), then only the reference is passed, ***even if you pass the argument `ByVal`***.

The difference between `ByVal` and `ByRef` for reference types is `ByVal` gives you a *copy –ie value– of the reference*. With `ByRef` you have the *original reference itself* (it's functionally the *same variable* as from the call site).

Let's look at a simple example to better understand how this matters:

```vb
Class Foo
    Public Bar As String
End Class

Module ConsoleProgram

    Sub PassByVal(ByVal baz As Foo)
        baz.Bar = "ByVal Property Set"
        baz = New Foo() With {.Bar = "New Object" }
    End Sub
    Sub PassByRef(ByRef baz As Foo)
        baz.Bar = "ByRef Property Set"
        baz = New Foo() With {.Bar = "New Object" }
    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        Dim baz As New Foo() With { .Bar = "test" }
        
        PassByVal(baz)
        Console.WriteLine(baz.Bar) ' Will write "ByVal Property Set"
        PassByRef(baz)
        Console.WriteLine(baz.Bar) ' Will write "New Object"
    End Sub
End Module
```

Notice the bodies of the two methods are effectively identical, and the only difference is how the argument is passed. See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z0Zq8a

So we see both `ByVal` and `ByRef` act on the original object, but only `ByRef` allows us to **replace** the original reference. In fact, in .Net, you should **almost never** use `ByRef` at all, which is why VB.Net was updated a number of years ago to not require you specify these at all and will let you just assume `ByVal` (it used to be required to provide one of these for every parameter when declaring methods).

Therefore we see .Net does **NOT** have to copy the `NodesCache` object data to use this method... just a 24 byte reference to the existing object.

---

The above also helps explain why iterators do not allow `ByRef` arguments (again: this is *not the same* as not allowing you to pass or use reference types). What happens behind the scenes is *the compiler generates a new class you didn't write*, and further creates an instance of this class which holds a reference to each of your arguments as members. If these arguments are `ByRef`, rather than `ByVal`, there could be unintended side effects outside of the iterator.

Comment: This is a clear and comprehensive answer and solution for my question thank you Joel!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your direct question about what happens in the background:

As with `Async` and `Await`, when you write an `Iterator` function, the compiler converts your code into a new class behind the scenes.  Local variables in the function (including arguments) are captured as fields in the class, and I would presume that function arguments end up getting converted into constructor arguments.

Given this, there would be a substantial amount of effort required to support `ByRef` arguments.  Remember that this is ultimately in support of an implementation of `IEnumerable(Of T)`, and the `IEnumerable` members don't include arbitrary arguments.  There would need to be special support to copy changes to anything `ByRef` back to the parent (and I could imagine additional complexity if there are multiple call levels).  Given that context, it's not surprising that the designers would choose to simply disallow `ByRef` arguments to `Iterator` functions.